# Parse.com iOS user email open readable after PFUser creation with PFLogInViewController

Tags: ios, security, parse-platform

I create a `PFUsers` at `Parse.com` with the `PFLogInViewController`. I want to give the user the option to change their username. For this I need to be able to check that a username is still unique. For this I need to be able to query the user.

Therefore I need to give a read access to the user object (`ACL`). If I do that the user's email address which is stored inside the user object is open readable in the internet :-(.

What is the best way to workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Parse docs](https://parse.com/docs/data#security-user):

> User Security
>
> It is important to keep in mind that the Parse User object is readable by all other users by default. You will want to set the ACL on your User object accordingly if you wish to prevent data contained in the User object (for example, the user's email address) from being visible by other users.
>
> There may be instances where you wish to provide selective read access to a Parse User object. For example, other users may wish to obtain a particular user's username, but you also want to prevent anyone from obtaining the user's email address. For situations like this, you will want to lock the object down by default and provide Cloud Code functions to access the parts of the Parse User object that you wish to expose to all users.

So, setup the ACL to lock down access to only the user themselves and provide cloud code to access anything else that users need to know about other users.

Comment: you say that you can lock down the User class to only user readwrite, but this SO answer says something quite contrary: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28732130/590767 that if you want SDK features to continue working, then it's necessary that _User still has a level of public access.

Is the cloud code route one where you basically don't use any SDK's? (e.g. ParseUI / Parse iOS SDK)

Comment: It isn't contrary, class permissions just didn't exist when this answer was written. If you lock down class level permissions then you need to use cloud code much more as you have the ability to use the master key there. Allowing general access makes queries easy, but that's because security is weak...

Comment: Sure, so not contrary. But does that mean you don't use any SDK functionalities? e.g. PFLoginViewController doesn't know about custom cloud functions, right. See https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/issues/200

Comment: Correct, you'd then need to use the delegate to handle the login yourself.